# Поиск адресов через suggestview и Placemark

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пробую сделать выбор города через suggestview и Placemark (что бы можно было указать адрес кликом по карте). Вариант при поиске города через suggestview я размещаю маркер на карте,и вот, так же когда кликаю по карте то меняю значения поля к которому прикреплен suggestview. И вот тут проблема  при изминении значения поля к которому прикриплен suggestview срабатывает наверное его событие onChange и опять предлагает выбрать адрес, если выбираю адрес то маркер перемещается и опять все по кругу.

Comment: приведите ваш код и опишите ваш вопрос подробнее, желательно пошагово

Comment: [Код здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/92d1bxr7/) Когда просто таскаеш маркер, то работает как нужно, но как только пробуеш искать через строку то подсказки уже не закрыть.

Comment: Пример реализации определения адреса клика на карте можно посмотреть [здесь](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode)